# What are these special class init imput elements in this source code?

Tags: python, class, init

**My situation:**

Below the documentation of the a module in the manim library (*[found here](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/_modules/manim/mobject/graphing/number_line.html#NumberLine)*) there have been some `__init__` arguments which confused me and I have not been able to reproduce them with a testing class.

A code snippet from the library:

```
def __init__(
        self,
        x_range: Sequence[float] | None = None,  # must be first
        length: float | None = None,
        ...
        line_to_number_buff: float = MED_SMALL_BUFF,
        decimal_number_config: dict | None = None,
        numbers_to_exclude: Iterable[float] | None = None,
        **kwargs,
    ):
...
```

**Question:**
Now I am wondering about multiple statements there. How can I understand the following code elements:

1. `x_range: Sequence[float] | None = None`
2. `length: float | None = None`
3. `line_to_number_buff: float = MED_SMALL_BUFF`
4. `decimal_number_config: dict | None = None`
5. `numbers_to_exclude: Iterable[float] | None = None`

**Precise questions:**

1. What happens if e.g. x_range is no `Sequence` and what happens if the `Sequence` is not of type `float`?
2. What happens for *point 3 above* if no entry of type `float` if passed into the argument? Is the `MED_SMALL_BUFF` a value if no specific value is specified?

**My assumptions:**

1. The colons specify the type of the element which are passed into the `__init__` dunder-method for the arguments.
2. The `|` is an logical or which sets the value before the colos equal to `None`. Nontheless I don't understand which `None` is set to `None` by `None = None`.

Comment: 1. those are type hints (plenty of resources about them online), idk what would happen if you didn't pass in the correct types (depends on the implementation) but the type hints don't enforce anything, also it's saying that you should pass in a sequence whose members are of type float. 2. `MED_SMALL_BUFF` is a default value which will be used if you don't provide your own value, again it just hints you that you should use a value of type `float` (usually it means that `int`egers work as fine)

Comment: There is no `None = None` here.  For example, `x_range` has a type hint (introduced by a colon) of `Sequence[float] | None`, and a default value (introduced by an equals sign) of `None`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Do the angluar brackets `[ ]` have any effect or is this just notational convention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values after `=` are the default values for the parameters. For instance, if you don't pass the `line_to_number_buff` argument, it defaults to `MED_SMALL_BUF`.

Where it has `sometype | None`, it means you can pass either a value of `sometype` or you can pass `None`. You're not generally expected to pass `None` explicitly (but you can); these parameters default to `None`, and the type hint allows for this.

If you don't pass a value of the type specified, you'll probably get an error. The function might check the type explicitly and report a `TypeError` itself, but more likely it just uses the value when calling some other code that expects that type. The bad value could propagate through numerous functions before it gets to something that actually checks, and that will report the error.